# Using Google Maps from a local webpage with Delphi & DCEF

Tags: delphi, google-maps, chromium

I am using Delphi & the DCEF (Delphi Chromium Embedded Framework) to load a local HTML file into a browser embedded within a form. The HTML file is trying to display a Google Map & has the line -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3.6&client=gme-{mycompanyid}"></script>
```

but the problem is that the URL sent as the referer to Google APIs is

```
HTTP://127.0.0.1/mypage.html
```

We have already authorised our website URLs for our Business Client ID, and we want to use the same Business Client ID for this desktop application.

My question is - how can I get the calls to Google API to use a different referer ? I think its not possible.

Comment: Just a guess, but what about to modify the request header in `OnBeforeBrowse` event ?

Comment: Thanks, I did try this. The OnBeforeBrowse event only fires when the page loads, not when the Google map tiles are retrieved.

Comment: I thought it is being sent just once when the map is initialized. Well, sorry then; unsuccessful guess...

Comment: it seems you are interested in the result. `The HTML file is trying to display a Google Map` . So why you not pass the correct URL `http://ourBusiness.com/myPage.html` to your embedded browser ?

Comment: @moskito-x - the HTML file is held locally, i.e. the embedded browser is loading url file://path/to/my/file/myPage.html, and the problem is then the Google scripts requesting the tiles from their API use this as the referer, I need them to use http://ourBusiness.com as the referer, because thats the authorised URL for our business use of the API.

Comment: It's easy to upload with delphi before call it with `ourBusiness.com` !

Answer (score 1):

Decided not to persue this, a locally hosted HTML file is really a security risk. We are still using the embedded DCEF browser in a Delphi form, but host the HTML file on our corporate webserver. That way the Google API is happy with the referring URL for map requests.

Thank you to all those who replied.